# Issue in sql server 2005 database diagram

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

### ```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express
```

Database diagram support objects cannot be installed because this database does not have a valid owner.  To continue, first use the Files page of the Database Properties dialog box or the ALTER AUTHORIZATION statement to set the database owner to a valid login, then add the database diagram support objects.

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is pretty self explanatory. Right click the database node in SSMS. Choose properties. Go to the "Files" page on the property dialogue that pops up. Set the owner.